# How to block showing p:growl message in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have defined a `p:growl` in my `xhtml` page like this:

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />.
```

When submit my form shows an error message for the required field when they are empty. And it highlights the required field with a red border. 
So I need highlighting part but don't want to show `p:growl`. But `p:growl` component is used for another purpose. How can I block showing
`p:growl` when required field is empty?

Answer (score 3):

Jens's variant make growl not to show ALL messages. Next solution works for me:

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to show the `p:growl` only when there is no validation error.

To achieve this you could add a rendered attribute to the growl component:

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" rendered="#{empty facesContext.messages}"/>
```

This will render the growl only if there is no validation error.

EDIT: I removed the `not` in the el.